# How graph specific data set in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, linegraph

I have a data frame as follows:

```
SVD <- structure(list(age.group = c("15-19", "20-24", "25-29", "30- 
34","35-39", "40-44", "45-49"), a = c(0.113152976, 0.302890507, 
0.274024612, 0.175444951, 0.09657695, 0.033532932, 0.004377071), b = 
c(0.107349538, 0.36591275, 0.244849695, 0.153582407, 0.094900555, 
0.030508273,0.002896782)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

I  need to plot them based on age groups. The final graph should be something like the ensuing graph:

[image]

Comment: Hi Mohammed. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Dear Allan, many codes with ggplot2. Unfortunately, none of them works and just a or b  graphed not both of them.

Comment: ggplot(data=SVD) + geom_point(aes(x=age.group,y=a,size=5)) + 
            geom_point(aes(x=age.group,y=b,size=5))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to reshape your data into long format:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

ggplot(pivot_longer(SVD, cols = c("a", "b")),
       aes(age.group, value, group = name, linetype = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Initial Age for Each Age Group",
       y = "Proportional Share of Fertility",
       linetype = "") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**Data taken from question**

```r
SVD <- structure(list(age.group = c("15-19", "20-24", "25-29", "30-34", 
"35-39", "40-44", "45-49"), a = c(0.113152976, 0.302890507, 0.274024612, 
0.175444951, 0.09657695, 0.033532932, 0.004377071), b = c(0.107349538, 
0.36591275, 0.244849695, 0.153582407, 0.094900555, 0.030508273, 
0.002896782)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Dear Allan Cameron, Thank you. I really appreciate your help.